# Github 2 repositories with different changes

Tags: git, github

I have 2 repositories which are deferent versions. Let's say the name of the my repository is Public/myrepo (Public is the username) which I clone from a public repository Mine/myrepo (Mine is the username) and push it to my github. The repositories have 3 subdirectories A,B,C. The directory had Public/myrepo/A/a and I alter the a directory and commit changes to my repository Mine/myrepo. After my commit the B directory altered from the public directory and they add a folder Public/myrepo/A/b. I want to have the Public/myrepo/A/b inside Mine/myrepo/A and the changes of Public/myrepo/B. How to do that?

Comment: you could try using git submodules but this sounds _a bit_ like a potential XY problem. Can you not use build tools instead (with the common part as a dependency)?

Comment: Do you want all the changes in Public/myrepo, or only the changes to B? If you want all the changes, just merge the main branch from Public/myrepo into Mine/myrepo and Git will apply what's changed in Public to your version.